# Required input text field with radio Button event in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, radio-button

I'm using radio button event.If I choose "Married" option three input text fields(validated by form control) will pop up (Check the image link).
If I choose other three radio buttons still the validation for three input text fields are enabled therefore I couldn't submit the form.

I have to write logic in "isSelectedmethod()" but I don't know how to write it.

```
// Radio button Selection 
private selectedLink: string = "";

setradio(e: string): void {
  this.selectedLink = e;
}
isSelected(name: string): boolean {
  if (this.selectedLink === "Married") {

    //that three input text fields validation should be enabled here  
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

[Check the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJOxB.png),

[Repo Link](https://github.com/jeyamaal/sampleAngular-2)

Comment: Are you hiding the fields when "married" is not selected? Or are you completely removing it from the DOM?

Comment: it will remove from DOM 

" <div class="form-group" id="spouseDetail" *ngIf="isSelected('Married')">"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize disable for this, form fields that are disabled, are excluded from the form object completely, and thus does not affect the validity of the form. So check which value is selected and then call `disable()` or `enable()` on the form fields. Also I would change your code a bit and remove the extra variable `selectedLink` and the methods. I do not encourage to call methods in the template, as they are called on each change detection. So this is what I would do:

```ts
this.personalForm = this.fb.group({
  radioCiviStatus: [''],
  spouseName: [{ value: '', disabled: true }, [Validators.required]],
  spouseOccupation: [{ value: '', disabled: true }, [Validators.required]],
  // ...
});

// listen to the change of the radio button and disable/enable fields accordingly:
this.personalForm.controls.radioCiviStatus.valueChanges
  .subscribe(value => {
    if (value === "Married") {
      this.personalForm.get('spouseName').enable();
      this.personalForm.get('spouseOccupation').enable();
    } else {
      this.personalForm.get('spouseName').disable();
      this.personalForm.get('spouseOccupation').disable()
    };
  });
```

Here's a

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdwe2g?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)